# react native rendering data prematurely

Tags: javascript, react-native

We have a feature where users can discuss in 3 different topics. This topics are displayed with a flatlist:

```
<View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }}>
    <FlatList
      horizontal
      data={categories}
      extraData={
      selectedCategory // for single item
    }
      style={styles.flatList}
      renderItem={({ item: rowData }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setSelectedCategory(rowData)}
          style={rowData === selectedCategory ? styles.selected : styles.unselected}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#FFFFFF', padding: 6 }}>
            { rowData }
          </Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.toString()}
    />
  </View>
```

our issue is when we change topics, the data is rendering prematurely, thus rendering the wrong category data several times. a screen grab here can show you the issue better that I can explain it in words: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQQue.jpg

Once it stops, it might settle and display the correct topic data, or it might show another topics data (such as moves when you are on memes).

Here is our code to display a topic's data:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCollection();
}, [selectedCategory]);

const getCollection = async() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  const index = 1;
  const getThoughtsOneCategory = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getThoughtsOneCategory');
  return getThoughtsOneCategory({
    index,
    category: selectedCategory,
  }).then((result) => {
    setThoughts(result.data);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

and our results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQQue.jpg

any idea what we can do to make sure the data being displayed is the correct topic/category, and to stop the flickering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making the call to firebase asynchronous fixed the issue:

```
const getThoughtsOneCategory = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getThoughtsOneCategory');
```